# Snake game, tentativa de um principiante C/C++

Tags: c, c++

Olá, estou a fazer o jogo da cobra, porém estou a fazer com uma matriz, a maneira que estou a fazer é dar prints e system("cls") rapidamente, porém gostava de saber maneiras mais eficientes, como por expemplo o gotoxy
Codigo para dar print à tela:

```
int i, j;
cout<<setw(MaxL/2 +5)<<"SNAKE GAME"<<endl;
for(i=0; i<MaxC; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<MaxL; j++)
    {
        if(j==MaxL-1)
            cout<< ScreenPrint[i][j]<<endl;
        else
            cout<<ScreenPrint[i][j];

    }

}
```

Desta forma consigo saber facilmente as coordenadas onde está cada coisa e saber quando chego ao limite:
Codigo que atualiza os valores da cobra, de acordo com as teclas W,A,S,D:
 Gety Retorna o valor y da snake, Getx retorna o valor x da snake
   SetY() atualiza coordenadas, -1 para fazer y-- e 1 para fazer y++

```
switch(toupper(c))    {
case 'W':
    ScreenPrint[GetY()][GetX()]=' ';
    setY(-1);
    ScreenPrint[GetY()][GetX()]=254;
    break;
case 'A':
    ScreenPrint[GetY()][GetX()]=' ';
    setX(-1);
    ScreenPrint[GetY()][GetX()]=254;
    break;
case 'S':
    ScreenPrint[GetY()][GetX()]=' ';
    setY(1);
    ScreenPrint[GetY()][GetX()]=254;
    break;
case 'D':
    ScreenPrint[GetY()][GetX()]=' ';
    setX(1);
    ScreenPrint[GetY()][GetX()]=254;
    break;
default:
    break;
}

/*  SCREEN LIMIT */
if(GetX()<=0 || GetY()<=0 || GetX()>=MaxL-1 || GetY()>=MaxC-1)
         return -1;

else
    return 1;
```

Para concluir, gostava de saber possiveis bibliotecas a adicionar, formas diferentes para fazer, novas ideias, ainda nao sei utilizar muito bibliotecas para alem das standards, agredecia ajuda.
Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o [SDL2](https://www.libsdl.org/) para criar a janela e "desenhar" os sprites na tela, ele tem suporte a áudio, dispositivos de entrada como teclado, mouse e joystick, APIs gráficas como Vulkan, OpenGL e DirectX, creio que com apenas ela você já tem o suficiente para criar seu clone, 2 exemplos de clones do snake com SDL:

- https://github.com/mahiuchun/Snake-SDL
- https://github.com/spajus/sdl2-snake

Comment: Isso parece ser um pouco complicado, mas vou tentar, obrigado.

Comment: @FábioMorais dê uma olhada nos tutoriais de SDl deste site, eles podem lhe ajudar http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/

Comment: Era mesmo isso que precisava, posso fazer o jogo todo primeira na consola e depois começar a utilizar a biblioteca SDL2? Ou existem funções que ajudam à construçao do snake game?
Tenho de fazer download da bilbioteca e depois importar no projeto?

Comment: @FábioMorais Com o sdl você pode por exemplo carregar a imagem da cobra para a tela e move-la com os eventos de teclas http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/02_getting_an_image_on_the_screen/index.php

Comment: http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/04_key_presses/index.php